# CSRF Failed SSO Django after redirect

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, google-sso

I'm trying to configure Google's SSO for my django app. Google is the Identity provider and my app is the Service provider. I'm using [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml) for the SSO and I used the files like in the [django demo](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/tree/master/demo-django). Whenever I click login, Google tries to login but it returns a 403 saying `csrf verification has failed`. Any idea where I should be looking?

For the files, I used the exact same as described in the demo mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'fixed' it by bypassing the csrf check on the view using the decorator `@csrf_exempt` that rendered the response. The csrf cookie cannot be set because the POST came from a 3rd party (Google, in this particular case) and is not necessary here as SAML already checks the response. See: https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml/issues/146